# how to make window service depend on remote database server service

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-services

I have created a window service and set dependency on SQL server service.

But the problem is if my service and SQL server service is on same machine then dependency is working fine but if they are on different servers then what i can do to enforce dependency. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to only start your service when SQL Server is running, or do you actually only want your service to perform its tasks when it can access a specific database? Service dependencies aren't meant for this, and the fact that a SQL Server service is running doesn't mean the instance and database you're looking for are available. Explain what actual problem you're trying to solve, so we can give you a subtle push in the right direction.

Comment: But if you insist, see [How to set up dependencies between windows-services on different servers in same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508892/how-to-set-up-dependencies-between-windows-services-on-different-servers-in-same): you can't.

Comment: yes, i only want to check database connection..

Comment: Can't you just wrap your database connection code in a `try .. catch` block and retry after some time? Does it _have_ to be a Windows Service, or can it also be a Scheduled Task which runs every few minutes or hours and just exits silently when the database is not yet available?