# How to stop windows service that contains multiple threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i am using system.Thread.Timer class to create a thread.  while stopping the main windows service i want to gracefully close all these child service threads in OnStop Event of Windows service?

Comment: Are you asking us what do you want to do?

Comment: See this answers : [How to set up dependencies between windows-services on different servers in same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508892/how-to-set-up-dependencies-between-windows-services-on-different-servers-in-same)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how you can do this. In short, you want to "cancel" or stop the work that your thread's doing. For this you can use one of the following:

- Use a `volatile bool` field to see if cancelation was requested if you use a `Thread` class
- Use `Task` cancelation, if you use a `Task` class
- Use wait handles (`AutoResetHandle` or `ManualResetHandle`) with `Thread`
- Cancel `BackgrounWorker`

Don't use `thread.Abort`, to learn more search for "thread abort is evil"